# Upload Image with comments under forums

Tags: media, comments, nodes

In drupal 7 Forums under some topic I want to add a upload image field with the comment field. How can i achive this?

Answer (score 1):

## Install **[CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor)**

[image]

> This module will allow Drupal to replace textarea fields with the CKEditor - a visual HTML editor, usually called a WYSIWYG editor. This HTML text editor brings many of the powerful WYSIWYG editing functions of known desktop editors like Word to the web. It's very fast and doesn't require any kind of installation on the client computer.

## [As mentioned by darol100](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186150/upload-image-with-comments-under-forums/186151?noredirect=1#comment-225636), for Upload Install [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce)

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
> directories and quota.

[image]

#### Here is a nice video tutorial: [Installing and Using CKEditor and IMCE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VTEI8tNEMw)

Comment: I have installed this module but it is allowing to upload image by a url, but I want to allow to upload image from local computer.

Comment: You need to install [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) too. So the user can upload the images to your server.

Comment: Then in CKEditor, you have to change its settings so it uses IMCE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for image captions, Here are couple of modules to do that..

[**Image Field Caption**](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption)

> Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.
>
> Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image
>   field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html
>   descriptions of an image.

**[Image Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption)**

> This module uses JQuery to dynamically add captions to images. The
>   image title attribute is used to create the caption. It basically
>   wraps the image in an html container div, takes the image title text
>   and appends that in a child div underneath the image. Technically, it
>   works by implementing Drupal's hook_nodeapi to add one small snippet
>   of captioner jquery to the head section of the page when a node of the
>   configured type is viewed.